# Nginx location regex generic

Tags: regex, nginx, nginx-location

A static site has html files in directories per language http://example.com/en 
For example locations 
/en/   (english)
/es/   (spanish)
The static files includes css are directed to the site root, that works, 
/en/css/style.css -> directed to /css/style.css

```
        location ~ "^/en/(img|js|css)" {
            rewrite                   ^/en(.*)$ $1 last;
        }
        location ~ "^/es/(img|js|css)" {
            rewrite                   ^/es(.*)$ $1 last;
        }
```

If I now want to add 40 languages, i have to duplicate above location 40 times, How would i make this so that i do not have to duplicate the location for every language code,
Is it possible to capture the /two letter lang code/ and reuse it in the rewrite?

Many Thanks!

Comment: have you tried `(?:es|en|fr|ge...)` ? use OR `|` so it will match atleast one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a capture in the `location` statement to construct the regular expression in the `rewrite` statement. Regular expressions are literals and cannot be constructed using variables.

However, you don't need to...

The `rewrite` statement inside your `location` block only sees URIs where the value between the first two `/`s should be ignored.

For example:

```
location ... {
    rewrite ^/[^/]+(/.*)$ $1 last;
}
```

If all of the language codes are two characters long, you could generalise further with:

```
location ~ "^/[a-z]{2}/(img|js|css)" {
    rewrite ^/[^/]+(/.*)$ $1 last;
}
```

But, there are many other solutions that will work. If these are static files, the `rewrite` may be unnecessary, for example:

```
location ~ "^/[a-z]{2}(/(img|js|css).*)$" {
    try_files $1 =404;
}
```